# Permission error when compiling in qtcreator under windows 10

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, mingw-w64

I am having trouble with qtcreator in windows 10 64 bit. I did a clean installation but I am not able to compile anything. It always fails with thefollowing errors:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\share\cmake-3.19\Modules\CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:48: error: Failed to open C:/Users/ASUS PRO/Documents/3annoMatIng/PCS-2020-21/I_miei_esercizi/exercises/1_c++_python_base/Exercise_1/build-C++-Desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt Permission denied C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:26 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI) CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\share\cmake-3.19\Modules\CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:46: error: Failed to open C:/Users/ASUS PRO/Documents/3annoMatIng/PCS-2020-21/I_miei_esercizi/exercises/1_c++_python_base/Exercise_1/build-C++-Desktop_x86_windows_msvc2017_pe_64bit-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt Permission denied CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\share\cmake-3.19\Modules\CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59: error: The C++ compiler "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/g++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program. It fails with the following output:

:-1: error: CMake process exited with exit code 1.
```

There seems to be a permissions error, I already ried to run qtcreator as administrator, but it continues to give the same error. I followed an installation guide provided  my lecture very carefully, but it doesn't work for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, I 've been tring to fix this all day and I don't know what to do

The configuration is the following:

[image]

Comment: On Windows paths may not be longer than 260 characters by default. And even though there is an option to enable longer paths for Windows 10, most applications still can't handle these correctly. I haven't counted the number of characters in your build path, but it seems pretty long to me, so that might be the issue. If that is the case changing the build directory to something else should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the antivirus, that was silently blocking Cmake. The fix was to add an exception in the antivirus for the qtcreator installation directory and for the qtcreator project directory